# How to cache downloaded PIP packages

Tags: python, pip

How do you prevent PIP from re-downloading previously downloaded packages? I'm testing the install of matplotlib, an 11MB package that depends on several distro-specific packages. Everytime I run `pip install matplotlib`, it re-downloads matplotlib. How do I stop this?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

You can use a specific environment variable **PIP_DOWNLOAD_CACHE** and make it point to a directory where your packages will be stored. If they are to be installed again, they will be taken from this directory.

There seems to be also an additional option for PIP `pip --download-cache` which ought to do something similar, but I have never tried it myself. For your example, to avoid re-downloading `matplotlib` every time, you would do the following:

```
pip install --download-cache /path/to/pip/cache matplotlib
```

Does that answer your question?

Comment: I'm not sure if PIP does it too, but with `easy_install` if you have the package as a `.tar` (or presumably zip?) file in the local directory it will try to use that one first.

Comment: Do look at [pip-accel](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip-accel) as well. It's a new and better solution to this problem.

Comment: as of pip 8 `--download-cache` was dropped, pip should be using cache by default that can be turned off with `--no-cache-dir`

Comment: I don't see PIP_DOWNLOAD_CACHE mentioned in https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/topics/caching/ - but I guess this is where we find out about generic pip env vars: https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/topics/configuration/#environment-variables

Comment: RIP pip-accel :((((

Answer (score 114):

**NOTE**: Only wheels downloaded over **HTTPS** are cached. If you are using a custom repo over plain old HTTP, [the cache is disabled](https://github.com/pypa/pip/pull/9498).

## For new Pip versions:

Newer Pip versions by default now cache downloads. See this documentation:

https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/topics/caching/

## For old Pip versions:

Create a configuration file named `~/.pip/pip.conf`, and add the following contents:

```
[global]
download_cache = ~/.cache/pip
```

In one command:

```
printf '[global]\ndownload_cache = ~/.cache/pip\n' >> ~/.pip/pip.conf
```

Comment: Cool, easy and do not need to remember adding the parameter each time. I wasted a LOT of Gb's re-downloading shit. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you, if you use pip3 to download requirements and get yellow text warning, you can mkdir ~/.cache/pip then the warning will go away.

Comment: I added a note to use HTTPS. There's a setting `--trusted-host option` that can enable caching over HTTP for a specific domain in pip 21.3 (2021-10-11).

Comment: By the way, what is the life time (TTL) of a package in pip cache ?

Answer (score 8):

You could

```
# download and extract package to build path
pip install --no-install matplotlib

# the build path could be found by 
pip install --help|grep Unpack\ packages\ into -A 2

# then rm pip-delete-this-directory.txt inside the build path
# this prevent pip from removing package from the build directory after install
# you could check the content of the file
rm build/pip-delete-this-directory.txt

# from now on you could install matplotlib quickly
# this uses single build directory 
# and can speed up compiling by caching intermediate objects.
pip install --no-download matplotlib
```

Also, you could manually download the package

```
pip install -d dir_for_packages matplotlib
```

Then install it by un-tar and `python setup install` later.

The `pip install --download-cache` works in a similar way w/ extra checking: it firstly search for the latest or specified version of the target package from web, if the search has result and there is cached package in the directory specified by `download-cache`, the cached package will be used instead of downloading. For example,

```
pip install --download-cache . pymongo
```

will download pymongo package to current directory:

```
http%3A%2F%2Fpypi.python.org%2Fpackages%2Fsource%2Fp%2Fpymongo%2Fpymongo-2.1.1.tar.gz
http%3A%2F%2Fpypi.python.org%2Fpackages%2Fsource%2Fp%2Fpymongo%2Fpymongo-2.1.1.tar.gz.content-type
```

Comment: These options -albeit  useful- are no longer supported as of pip 7