# setuptools download cache path

Tags: python, setuptools

Can I set download cache path for setuptools? I can do that with pip by setting environment variable **PIP_DOWNLOAD_CACHE** ([How to cache downloaded PIP packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10336308/how-to-cache-downloaded-pip-packages)), but I don't know, what to do with setuptools.

I want everytime, when I run:

```
python setup.py develop
```

the setuptools caches the downloaded files, so I don't have to download it again.

Comment: Isn't this similar with what you want? http://stackoverflow.com/a/11092043/471481 I might be wrong or misread your question

Comment: Thanks for reply. I mean 'cache' for pip, not require_packages. About my question, I think that there's not a solution for it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the options `-a`, `-d` and `-f` to create and use a cache directory. This is what the help text for them says:

```
--always-copy (-a)             Copy all needed packages to install dir
--install-dir (-d)             install package to DIR
--find-links (-f)              additional URL(s) to search for packages
```

You first use `python setup.py develop -a -d CACHEDIR` to cache the needed packages in the directory of your choice, then use that directory as a source in the future with `python setup.py develop -f CACHEDIR`.

You may need to add any flags you normally use to one, the other, or both invocations, depending on the flag in question.

Comment: Is there any way to add -f to environment variable, such as SETUPTOOL_FIND_LINK ?

Comment: @Tarzan, not to my knowledge.