# How can I reduce pip installation time in docker beyond just caching package downloads?

Tags: docker, caching, pip, requirements.txt

When running pip within docker, I've found out from many excellent SO answers how to cache downloading of packages, i.e. for example

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:experimental
...

RUN --mount=type=cache,mode=0755,id=pip,target=/root/.cache/pip \
    pip3 install -r requirements.txt --target /root/.cache/pip
```

This caches the downloads appearing in requirements.txt, but not the installation itself. The problem is that if I update requirements.txt with a new package - assuming no shared dependencies change - one only saves on download time (which in this case is only about half the docker build time).

Now I could just add new packages one-by-one in the dockerfile, but then I have to circle back round for the inevitable squash into a single RUN line - the time hit is unavoidable if one wants to simplify the dockerfile and minimize the image size.

So, is there a way to speed up the build even further by caching more than just the package downloads?

Thanks as ever!

REFS:

[Using a pip cache directory in docker builds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58018300/using-a-pip-cache-directory-in-docker-builds)

[How to avoid reinstalling packages when building Docker image for Python projects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25305788/how-to-avoid-reinstalling-packages-when-building-docker-image-for-python-project)

[How to cache downloaded PIP packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10336308/how-to-cache-downloaded-pip-packages)

Comment: May I recommend Itamar Turner-Trauring's excellent [set of articles on Docker+Python](https://pythonspeed.com/docker), especially [Fast builds, small images](https://pythonspeed.com/docker#fast-builds-small-images) section?